# What is this giant seedling?

Tags: identification, seedlings

I set up an experimental seed starting tray, but can' remember exactly what seed I put for some seedlings. One of them is a HUGE seedlings pictured in photos below.

I just vaguely remember that it could be an Agastache, or so some form of mentha.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think this is the second one of the same kind, just at the early stage of development:

[image]

---

Update:

It turns out it was Cucurbita pepo - decorative pumpkin. Out of 8 seeds, 2 germinated. Those two seedlings are now in their own containers:

[image]

You may have noticed that a cotyledon of the smaller seedlings is whorled. I posted a separate question on that: [Why is my pumpkin seedling's cotyledon twisted and whorled?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/37918/why-is-my-pumpkin-seedlings-cotyledon-twisted-and-whorled)

---

Update 2:

I already thought there will be no more pumpkin seedlings, but two more appeared this afternoon - boy, they are moving earth:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like [pumpkin](https://www.featurepics.com/online/Pumpkin-Seedling-2021538.aspx), Vivid. You don't remember what you sowed?

Comment: Or a relative, but whichever *exact* breed, I think you are spot on.

Comment: If you didn't sow pumpkins, then what about marrow/courgette? Most if not all squashes start out like this. And from the first sign of germination to your last picture takes only a few hours; the big one is overdue for its first potting up

Comment: Some variety of vinous plant, certainly. I'll take a guess at summer squash or zucchini.

Comment: I agree with the comments here, it might also be Zucchini or other relatives. My first impression was pumpkin, but could definitely be other family members.

Comment: I recalled that I sow in these cells so called "decorative pumkin" seeds, so this answer is very good, but thanks to other commenters as well! @BobJarvis

Comment: It looks it is "decorative pumkin", thanks for other hints! Both plants are in separate containers now. @ChrisH